# Need to get the values in email body

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val TimeFormat = 20:30:16
val count = 3500
```

I am sending the above value through spark scala program in email body and i am not able to get those values:

```
var bodyText = "Hello EveryOne, \n\n  No of records :  + count  \n  Total Time Taken to Load the Data:  + TimeFormat  \n\n\n Thanks \n ABC."
```

The email that i am getting is as below

```
Hello EveryOne,

  No of records :  + count  
  Total Time Taken to Load the Data:  + TimeFormat  
 Thanks
```

But i need the values in the email.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently building one string literal (your email body). You must divide it into multiple string literals and concatenate these and your constants:

```
var bodyText = "Hello EveryOne, \n\n  No of records : " + count + " \n  Total Time Taken to Load the Data: " + TimeFormat + " \n\n\n Thanks \n ABC."
```

An alternative is the 's' string interpolator. It allows you to reference variables from string literals using the dollar sign. More details [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html):

```
var bodyText = s"Hello EveryOne, \n\n  No of records : $count \n  Total Time Taken to Load the Data: $TimeFormat  \n\n\n Thanks \n ABC."
```